# error de servidor interno El servidor encontró un error interno y no pudo completar su solicitud. FLASK

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Hola a todos soy nuevo en flask y recurro a ustedes para poder solucionar mi error, tengo este problema de error de servidor , lo extraño es que a nivel local me funciona perfecto pero a nivel servidor se cae con este error.

```
**@app.route('/analisisRelativo/<cod_entidad>/<anio>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def analisisRelativo(cod_entidad, anio):
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    parametros = {'cod_entidad': cod_entidad}
    cursor.execute("""select cod_entidad,desc_entidad from entidad where cod_entidad =%(cod_entidad)s""", parametros)
    rest = cursor.fetchone()
    if not rest:
        abort(404)
    entidad = rest[1]
    data, columnas = get_analisisRelativo(cod_entidad, anio)
    data = list(data)
    return render_template("/analisisrelativo.html", entidad=entidad, data=data, columnas=columnas,
                           cod_entidad=cod_entidad, anio=anio)**
```

Comment: Buenas. Creo que no has puesto el error, ¿no?  Solo el código.

Comment: ya lo solucione miguel gracias era que windows interpreta en los template las mayusculas y linux no la interpretaba pero era eso muchas gracias de todos modos